# Why "\r\n" don't work?

Tags: php

I feel little dumb asking this, but I already tested everything that was on my mind to try fix this, and nothing worked. I'm calling a function doing echo as showed in this code:

> echo showInfos($uid, $con);

Ok, the showInfos function is this:

```
function showInfos($uid, $con)
{
    $ret = '';
    $query =    "SELECT Name, ProcName, ByteType, InsertTime FROM tableInfos WHERE uid = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($uid, $con) . "'";
    $res = mysql_query($query, $con);
    if($res)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $ret .= '----New Track Data ::'."\r\n".'..ProcName:'.$row['ProcName']."\r\n";
        }       
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

As you can see I'm adding "\r\n" in my return... But for some unknown reason my browser still showing everything in this way:

----New Track Data :: ..ProcName:notepad.exe ----New Track Data :: ..ProcName:notepad.exe ----New Track Data :: ..ProcName:notepad.exe

I think it should be something like:

----New Track Data ::

..ProcName:notepad.exe

----New Track Data ::

..ProcName:notepad.exe

What's going on?
Thank for attention!

Comment: The browser ignores newline characters when rendering HTML, use `<br/>` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because \r and \n are treated as whitespace by the browser. If you want to create a newline in a browser, you'll need to use an HTML element like `<br />`.

Comment: ... or you can echo your stuff inside a `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You are echoing whitespace, which browsers just ignore. Browsers need tags to format text, so you need to convert the whitespace newline into a html tag, `<br />` in php you can use the [`nl2br()`](http://be1.php.net/nl2br) function for this.

```
echo nl2br("test line 1\ntest line 2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone is saying, you need `<br/>` tags for line breaks in HTML.

***Alternatively***, if you want to share a block of pre-formatted text like program code or debug output you can also wrap that block in `<pre> </pre>` tags and your whitespace will be respected by the browser.